# Error when saving BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi+, bitmapsource

I have a problem when I try to save a BitmapSource. I alsways get an error in GDI+ or that the file is in use by another proces.

The methode to save the bitmapimage

```
protected override void Save()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Thumbnail.ToBitmap();

    if (Angle % 360 == 0)
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
    else if (Angle % 270 == 0)
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    else if (Angle % 180 == 0)
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
    else if (Angle % 90 == 0)
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

    bitmap.Save(Objects[0].FilePath);
    Objects[0].RaisePropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
}
```

BitmapSource to Bitmap conversion

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
        enc.Save(stream);

        using (var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
        {
            return new Bitmap(tempBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

The "Thumbnail"  that is used to save comes from a get-property

```
public BitmapSource Image
{
    get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri(FilePath)); }
}
```

And the thumbnail of the file is also used in a view. I get it with the windows shell api.

```
public static BitmapSource GetThumbnail(this string This, BitmapSize size = BitmapSize.Large)
{
    if (ShellObject.IsPlatformSupported)
    {
        ShellObject shellitem = ShellObject.FromParsingName(This);

        try
        {
            if (size == BitmapSize.Small)
                return shellitem.Thumbnail.SmallBitmap.ToBitmapSource();
            else if (size == BitmapSize.Medium)
                return shellitem.Thumbnail.MediumBitmap.ToBitmapSource();
            else if (size == BitmapSize.Large)
                return shellitem.Thumbnail.LargeBitmap.ToBitmapSource();
            else
                return shellitem.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap.ToBitmapSource(); ;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

        return null;
    }
```

Does anyon has a solution?

Thanks
Wim

Comment: on what line exactly you get this exception?

Comment: A bitmap Image is a loader for the file, it maintains the image source in an open state, if you disable caching then it should close the datasource after loading

Comment: The error occures in the bitmap.Save(...)

Comment: And where do i disable the caching?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Application.current.dispatcher

```
Application.current.dispatcher(()=>Save());
```

Comment: Bitmap image has a Dispatcher property, would be better to use that than the Application's